# How many records can be possible in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

How many records can be possible & how many maximum records can be effective in mysql?

Actually my table has 
  24 Tables
  1000000  Rows in Table (Each table (max))

Can I use mysql, please help me to solve my problem.

Comment: You don't appear to have a problem. With appropriate hardware and partitioning, there's almost no limit

Comment: mysql won't have a problem with 24 million rows ^^

Comment: people in this thread have over 400 million rows.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14733462/can-mysql-handle-tables-which-will-hold-about-300-million-records

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can use mysql perfectly.
One million rows (AKA records) is not too much for mysql, if you index that.